# Will the mobile network connection work on the Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, mobile-broadband

I'm planning to buy a Nexus 7 to use it as a small car PC. Can you tell me, what is the current state of using the mobile broadband connection and the GPS hardware of the Nexus 7 in Ubuntu Touch?

Thank you and best wishes,
Peter

Answer (score 3):

Currently it looks like that version is not supported:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArLs7UPtu-hJdDZDNWliMmV1YUJ3Zk1pQlpDdGp4VFE#gid=0

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

You can probably build it yourself, but that is a lot of effort.

Always check the Wiki!!

Answer (score 1):

With the TASEMNICE port for Nexus 7 LTE it will work.